# How to stop chrome browser on android from destroying PHP sessions?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I've my code working like this

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    #DO THINGS
}
else
{
    #TAKE USER TO LOGIN PAGE
}
?>
```

My problem is that whenever close my chrome browser(on my android phone) and reopen it; it takes me to login page. Which led to the conclusion that my session got destroyed. It only happens with Chrome. I've tried it with UC Turbo(Android browser) and it kept me logged in. Can someone help?

Comment: It means the browser is clearing session cookies when you close it. This is a browser setting, nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by chrome on your phone and not by PHP, the solution will be to implement a cookie login system that will be kept across sessions.

The use of cookies is less secure than that of Sessions, please reference a recent article on the use of "remember me" cookies. I have found this article which demonstrates the concept, https://phppot.com/php/secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies/